# How do i extract text from double quotes and add it to string ? python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
import re
response_text = '{"captchaData":"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","captchaMime":"image/jpeg","captchaToken":"ALXfmJpxoaxq6LYBXm-kJzIl0Yd5mHG1XbttsBX-EKxMYtYNIc6uTv89fmRxeWZGEgpi2L9sjXYlkm6Vplav_wy2KjdB5J4j3i5fB6CEuPOMXIjEql6mPBJ8-YJTCpOzzk8kOcW5nuBbuLOdMVyVxquLbWjqLZzHeN0iT4Jm4SIZ9mQNfapNGkE","status":"CAPTCHA"}'
love = '"captchaData":"mydata"'
session_token_temp = re.search(r'(\"captchaData\":\")(\w*)', 
response_text).group()
session_token = str(session_token_temp)
```

i want to extract value of captchaData and captchaToken and add the data to string like this

```
extracted_data = (value_of_captchaData)
extracted_data2 = (value_of_captchaToken)
```

Comment: Can you give a precise example of desired input and output?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` instead of regex:

```
import ast
response_text = '{"captchaData":"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","captchaMime":"image/jpeg","captchaToken":"ALXfmJpxoaxq6LYBXm-kJzIl0Yd5mHG1XbttsBX-EKxMYtYNIc6uTv89fmRxeWZGEgpi2L9sjXYlkm6Vplav_wy2KjdB5J4j3i5fB6CEuPOMXIjEql6mPBJ8-YJTCpOzzk8kOcW5nuBbuLOdMVyVxquLbWjqLZzHeN0iT4Jm4SIZ9mQNfapNGkE","status":"CAPTCHA"}'
new_data = ast.literal_eval(response_text)
print(new_data["captchaData"])
print(new_data['captchaToken'])
```

Comment: This only works by accident. JSON and python dict format are kind of similar, but this will break as soon as something like `null` or `true` is used. I highly recommend you just use a JSON parser instead.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you are actually trying to do is to parse JSON. JSON is a format that is often used to represent data on the web.

If you are using requests (which it sounds like from the tag), you can use `.json()` to parse the result. Otherwise use the built-in `json` module.

```
r = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/get")
data = r.json()
```

or

```
import json

data = json.loads('"key": "value"')
```

Answer (score -1):

If all you want is to remove a given character before and after a string, you can use `strip`

```
'"some string"'.strip('"') # 'some string'
```